# Final assertion not passing in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

```
//drivercode
#include "team.h"
#include "team.h"
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TEAM_SIZE 10
#define DRAFT_SIZE TEAM_SIZE*TEAM_SIZE
#define PARTA 1
#define PARTB 1
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
#if PARTA
    ///////// PART A Tests /////////
    printf("\n\t======= Verifying Player Struct...\n\n");
    int player_num = 0;
    struct Player p1 = {rand()%TEAM_SIZE+1, rand()%TEAM_SIZE+1, player_num++};
    struct Player p2 = {rand()%TEAM_SIZE+1, rand()%TEAM_SIZE+1, player_num++};
    if(p1.offense > p2.defense){
        printf("\nPlayer%d wins with %d offense", p1.number, p1.offense);
        printf(" over Player%d's %d defense.\n", p2.number, p2.defense);
    }else if(p2.offense > p1.defense){
        printf("Player%d wins with %d offense", p2.number, p2.offense);
        printf(" over Player%d's %d defense.\n", p1.number, p1.defense);
    }else{
        printf("Player%d and Player%d tie the match.\n", p1.number, p2.number);
    }
    printf("\n\t...Passed =======\n\n");
    printf("\n\t======= Verifying Team Struct...");
    struct Team t1;
    for(int j = 0; j < 80; j++)  {
        t1.name[j] = '\0';
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < TEAM_SIZE; i++){
        //this tests that you have player objects inside your team players array.
        //'total' is a nonsensical throwaway value.
        t1.players[i].offense = t1.players[i].defense = t1.players[i].number = rand() % TEAM_SIZE;
        int total = t1.players[i].offense + t1.players[i].defense + t1.players[i].number;
        printf("%d, ", total);
    }
    printf("\nPassed =======\n\n");
#endif
#if PARTB
    ///////// PART B TESTS /////////
    printf("\n\t======= Single League Team Initialization...");

    struct Player draft[DRAFT_SIZE];
    initPlayers(draft, DRAFT_SIZE);
    struct Team league[TEAM_SIZE];
    league[0] = draftTeam("Prime", draft, TEAM_SIZE);
    int last_total = 0, counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < TEAM_SIZE; i++){
        int total = league[0].players[i].offense + league[0].players[i].defense + league[0].players[i].number;
        if(total == last_total){
            counter++;
        }
        last_total = total;
    }

    printf("Passed =======\n\n");
    printf("\n\t======= Multiple League Team Initialization...");

    for(int i = 1; i < TEAM_SIZE; i++){
        league[i] = draftTeam("Prime", draft, TEAM_SIZE);
        int last_total = 0, counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < TEAM_SIZE; j++){
            int total = league[i].players[j].offense + league[i].players[j].defense + league[i].players[j].number;
            if(total == last_total){
                counter++;
            }
            last_total = total;
        }
        assert(counter <= 3);
    }

    printf("Passed =======\n\n");
    printf("\n\t======= Verifying all players were drafted...");

        int t = -1;
        for(int j = 0; j < DRAFT_SIZE; j++){
            assert(draft[j].number == -1);
            if(j % 10 == 0) t++;
            assert(league[t].players[j%10].number != -1);
        }

    printf("Passed =======\n\n");
    printf("\n\tAll Tests Passed! \nMake sure to push to Github and submit your hash on MyCourses!\n\n");
#endif
}
```

```
//team.c file
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "team.h"

void initPlayers(struct Player players[], int size){
     for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
         players[i].offense = rand();
         players[i].defense = rand();
         players[i].number = rand();
     }
}
struct Team draftTeam(char name[], struct Player draft[],int team_size){
     struct Team bestteam;
     bestteam.name = name[]; 
     bestteam.players = draft[];
     for(int i=0; i<team_size;i++){
         bestteam.players[i] = draft[i];
         draft[i].number = -1;
     }
     return bestteam;
}
```

```
//team.h file
#ifndef JG_TEAM_H
#define JG_TEAM_H

struct Player{
     int offense;
     int defense;
     int number;
};
struct Team{
     struct Player players[10];
     char name[80];
};

void initPlayers(struct Player players[], int size);

struct Team draftTeam(char name[], struct Player draft[],int team_size);

#endif
```

When running the code "team.c" with the driver code I am able to pass every test except for the final test. When it gets to the final test I get the error `"a.out: main.c:83: main: Assertion draft[j].number == -1 failed. Aborted"` Is there something that I should be changing in my code so that I am able to pass this test?

Comment: Please could you narrow the problem down - that is a lot of code to digest

Comment: How does this even *compile* , much less run to an assertion failure ? : `bestteam.name = name[];` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you intend the last test to do? Why do expect to pass it?